# Unique array of hashes by key value

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, unique

OK, so... I have an array of hashes like this:

```
[
    { :id => 0, :text => "someText" },
    { :id => 1, :text => "anotherText" },
    { :id => 2, :text => "someText" }
]
```

What I want, is to `filter` hashes with removing duplicate `:text` values, so that the result is:

```
[
    { :id => 0, :text => "someText" },
    { :id => 1, :text => "anotherText" }
]
```

How can I do that?

---

P.S. Of course, I can find a way and do it. What I'm asking for is the best (& fastest) Ruby-friendly way, given that I'm not such a Ruby guru. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this by using **[Array#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq)**:

```
arr.uniq{|h| h[:text]} # Returns a new array by removing duplicate values
 => [{:id=>0, :text=>"someText"}, {:id=>1, :text=>"anotherText"}]
# OR    
arr.uniq!{|h| h[:text]} # Removes duplicate elements from self.
=> [{:id=>0, :text=>"someText"}, {:id=>1, :text=>"anotherText"}]
```

---

There will be many different approaches to achieve your goal but as you are looking for fastest way, Here is benchmark of both **uniq** and **group_by**. This is just for sample. Like this you can test yourself different approaches and check for the solution as per your requirements..

```
require 'benchmark'
arr = [{ :id => 0, :text => "someText" }, { :id => 1, :text => "anotherText" }, { :id => 2, :text => "someText" }]
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("group_by:")   { arr.group_by { |e| e[:text] }.values.map &:first }
  x.report("uniq:")   { arr.uniq{|h| h[:text]} }
end
# output
            user     system      total        real
group_by:  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000039)
uniq:      0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000012)
```

Comment: I think a fair warning should be given about second case as it mutates the value of the array itself.

Comment: @vjdhama : Sorry I didn't get you, but I have put the comment about both cases

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon : My pleasure. Glad to help you.

Answer (score 2):

While `uniq` is a perfect solution for the problem as it stated, there is more flexible approach where you are to specify an additional condition on what is to be picked out of multiple variants:

```
#                                        ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
arr.group_by { |e| e[:text] }.values.map &:first
```

One might put any condition there to select only those elements with even `:id`, or whatever.

Comment: mudasobwa : I have added benchmark just to make clear about fastest way to OP. My intention is not to prove your approach as wrong and mine right. So please don't mind and not misunderstood me. Anyways I am glad to know this new trick :)